# bullet point size shiny R list tag

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a very simple problem, but due to my lack of HTML skills and applying HTML attributes in shiny R, I cannot figure it out, so here it goes:

How do I increase the size of the bullet points of the list tag?

Is there a more detailed tutorial that explains the logic of using HTML code and attributes within the shiny R environment?

MEW:

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(shiny)
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {}) 

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
         tags$div(tags$ul(
                           tags$li("test1"),
                           tags$li("test2"),
                           tags$li("test3")),  style = "font-size: 15px")
                         )
    )

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a typical html page, you can have customized css in your header. Refer this link: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

```
library(shiny)
server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {}) 

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    li {
                    font-size: 36px;

                    }
                    li span {
                    font-size: 18px;
                    }
                    ul {
                    list-style-type: square;
                    }

                    "))
    ),

  tags$div(tags$ul(
    tags$li(tags$span("test1")),
    tags$li(tags$span("test2")),
    tags$li(tags$span("test3"))))
)
)

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thx but i only want to increase the size of the bullet points. Somehow, the li span options does not do anything for me in my code. I just do not understand how I would for instance change the bullet shape. I found type="square", but where would I add this?

Comment: @MaxM updated the code and output, please check. the span is to keep the font-size of the text same while changing the size of the bullet.

Comment: ok now it works, did you change anything else or just added the circle thing?

Comment: Missed the edit window... There are no known conflicts with the navbarPage environment. Your code works perfectly fine in the MWR, but not in my real code. I ll have to test it some more and come back if I cant fix it

Comment: Oh, Feel free to let me know if there's any further issue!

Comment: It seems that the li {font-size: 36px;}, does also affect the navbarPage environment, specifically the tabPanel. Should I rather edit my question or open a new question?  When I add navbarPage("test Page",
        tabPanel("Welcome Page", 
The "Welcome Page" is affected as well.